# Suppressing HTTP 500 response codes

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

I’ve had a bit of feedback from some threat and vulnerability folks relating to websites returning HTTP 500 response codes. Essentially the advice is that all possible measures must be taken to avoid the server throwing a 500 (i.e. extensive form input validation) which is fine.

However, the advice also suggested that attempts to compromise security by means such as inserting a  tag into a random query string causing ASP.NET request validation to fire or manipulating viewstate also should not return an HTTP 500. Obviously the native framework behaviour is to interpret the request and possibly throw to a custom error page but even this will return a 500 response code.

So I’m after some thoughts on how to approach this. Is there any way to configure the app at either the .NET level or IIS level to return an HTTP 200 when a 500 is raised? Or does this become a coding exercise at global.asax level in one of the application events? Are there other consequences to consider?

BTW, the rationale from the security side is that apps which return HTTP 500 may be viewed as “low hanging fruit” by bots randomly scanning for vulnerabilities and prompt further malicious activity. attempts I’m personally not convinced that changing response codes offers any real security gains but am happy to hapy to take the advice of the pros.

Comment: How does never throwing a 500 error code make you more secure?  Don't sound right to me, unless you're sticking debug info in your error page.

Comment: I’m talking about apps with custom errors on and no debug or trace data being surfaced. As I said above, the position is not that it makes the app more secure but rather that it makes it less visible as a potential candidate for intrusion attempts.

Comment: There's lots of other hints at what app you're using besides an error page (url patterns, form field names, HTML styles, custom HTTP headers...) so I don't know how much real security value suppressing an app's custom error page is.  Even if you do hide the app you're using, its just obfuscation.  Certainly "all possible measures" should not be taken, and certainly don't lie to the client about having an error.  MarkR has the best answer, create a generic, static, site wide 500 error page like Twitter's fail whale or Github's angry unicorn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To answer your question**: `global.asax` is the correct place, in particular, the `Application_Error` event handler. You should be able to do something like

```
Response.StatusCode = 200
Response.StatusDescription = "OK"
```

there.

**PS**: Don't do it. :-) To me, this sounds like yet another security-by-obscurity-by-violating-standards approach. I really don't think the (possibly marginal) security increase is worth breaking correct HTTP behavior (think about Google indexing your error pages, etc.).

Comment: I’ve marked this as the correct answer because although I agree with other responses in terms of it being something that shouldn’t be done, Heinzi is the only one who has actually answered the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Why? Sending back a 500 code without any other information does not give an attacker much information.

Provided you don't throw stack trace, state dumps etc, back to the client then you're fine. And I doubt very much you want to do that.

Seriously, just create a "500" page (picture of a whale optional) and return that with your status 500 - it gives nothing away.

Sending a 200 status when the page was NOT generated successfully is plain wrong and may cause bad things to happen - such as bots thinking it is a genuine page. You don't want your "500 error" page showing up on Google because you sent back a 200 status instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark, as I said, I have the same concerns and will probably try and negotiate out of it but at this stage I just need the actual implementation method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom error pages in config - and you could re-set the response status in your custom error page

```
<customErrors  mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/DefaultErrorPage.htm" >
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/CustomError.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Serious warning...!

Make sure there aren't any errors EVER in your custom error page. Usually, you would use a html page, not an aspx page - but if you want to change the response headers you may need to use the aspx page. Don't do anything else on there except change the headers (i.e. don't display any data from a database or try to run any logic) and error on your custom error page will cause a "maximum number of redirects" error.

Comment: Thanks Sohnee but your example only defines which error page to route to based on the HTTP status. It doesn't actually change the code in any way.