# Server randomly returning empty response with status code 200

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have the same site running on two different machines (behind the same firewall), same exact code. I have created a test plan with Jmeter that just hits the home page.  If I run with first url everything works as expected and get Size in bytes 17265.  If I then other size I get a size of 0. Both are returning 200 status.

Is there a setting on the server side that could be causing this? I dont think it is a Jmeter setting since all I am doing for the 2nd request it changing the URL

[image]
[image]

**ADDING INFORMATION**
My HTTP Request Default I just add the URL and change nothing else
[image]

For the HTTP Request I didn't actuall modify ANY setting
[image]

This it the response body from one server:
[image]

And this is the Other that is ALSO returning a 200 Status:
[image]

**Edit:**
I had seen that article but I had already had those features installed and working unless the is an additional setting somewhere in IIS that says even if these features are installed don't use them. Assuming that the errors in the logs would be under IIS there are no errors.

[image]

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198732/why-does-iis-return-empty-responses

Comment: Not quite the same because I can go to both in a browser and everything is fine one both. Pages look identical, only issue is when I am using jmeter

Comment: How is your request defined (and defaults)? As I don't see any indication of response data being recorded. I also noticed the header size is different and you didn't define the header manager. It could be nothing, but as you are connecting to two different webserver, small configuration differences could influence the outcome.... just pondering here ;-)

Comment: Note: I would have expected a HTTP/204 if your server didn't have anything to deliver.

Comment: I would have expected a 204 (or at least something other than 200) as well @RayOei I have add more screen shot.  I am adding the HTTP Requests and the only thing that is different is between tests I am changing the Server name on the HTTP Request Default

Comment: At this stage I would be interested to know what is in the headers. As you don't use a header manager, the jmeter call is likely different from what a browser requests. I would try to get that as similar as possible. My guess would still be that the webservers are not completely configured the same. But I am guessing. Have you tried Fiddler or Wireshark to see what is actually sent and received??

Comment: Did you check your IIS/application logs?

Comment: See also settings that will prevent not showing errors in IIS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173698/why-are-blank-pages-being-served-with-200-ok-for-asp-net-errors-in-iis-8-5-wi

Comment: @user7294900  why not write an answer instead of comment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server might be requiring headers such as Accept-Encoding which JMeter is not sending by default.

To add it in see here
[image]

As well here is a [JMX file](https://www.redline13.com/share/download/47883?path=testplan) testing your domain.  Disable the HTTP Header Manager and you will get a 200 status but no data.

Comment: Great Richard, @Lance just wondering why it works from 1 machine and not from another one.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure either and haven't investigated much. But now that I know what to look for I will post the reason once I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in your question this is not a JMeter issue.

It seems the server code or configuration might not be correct as per following links (mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294900/user7294900):

- [Why are blank pages being served with "200 OK" for asp.net errors in IIS 8.5 (Win 2012 R2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173698/why-are-blank-pages-being-served-with-200-ok-for-asp-net-errors-in-iis-8-5-wi)

And also this one:

- [Why does IIS return empty responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198732/why-does-iis-return-empty-responses)
- [Suppressing HTTP 500 response codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235182/suppressing-http-500-response-codes?rq=1)

Check server logs for error logs.

Comment: Please see my edit.  I have those things installed and have looked at that artical previously but it hasn't changed the behavior. I don't think I have anything that would be suppressing a valid 500 error and everything IS working because the browser display correctly.

Comment: Did you check what is written in this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235182/suppressing-http-500-response-codes?rq=1 ?

Comment: links are only supplement.

Comment: I read that question as their server is returning a 500 and they want it to return a 200 regardless whether there is an issue or not.  My server is already returning 200.  I have tried looking at it in a browser, with fiddler and with jmeter and fiddler.  the only real different I see in fiddler is the jmeter hit get a 0 content lenth and so never requests all the assets (css, js etc) but the browser doesn't get 0 content length and does request all of the assets.  I am beyond frustrated lol

Comment: Are you using distributed testing in JMeter for second test when you get empty response ?

Comment: Also can you try with JMeter 3.3 ?